# jUnit 5 HTML Report using Gradle 4.6

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, java-8, junit5, junit-jupiter

I am trying to generate HTML report of JUnit 5 test case.

Here is my Gradle.build file

```
   buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M3' 
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://zz-artifactory.zzzz.com/artifactory/maven' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.2.0-M1'
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.0.RC1"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
apply from: "CodeCoverage.gradle"


version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8


dependencies {
    compile('org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:1.3.2')
    compile('org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot:1.3.2')
    compile('org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter-test:1.3.2')

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')

    compile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.2.0-M1")
    compile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-migrationsupport:5.0.2')
    compile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.2.0-M1")
    compile("junit:junit:4.12")
    compile("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.2.0-M1")

    compile(group: 'org.junit.platform', name: 'junit-platform-launcher', version: '1.2.0-M1')
    compile(group: 'org.junit.platform', name: 'junit-platform-runner', version: '1.2.0-M1')

    testCompile('com.h2database:h2:1.4.196')
    testCompile('org.mockito:mockito-all:2.0.2-beta')
    testCompile('org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9')

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
 }

junitPlatform {
    // platformVersion '1.2.0-M1'
    filters {
        engines {
            // include 'junit-jupiter', 'junit-vintage'
            // exclude 'custom-engine'
        }
        tags {
             include 'Smoke'
            //exclude 'slow'
        }
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    test {
        reports.html.enabled = false
    }
}

task testReport(type: TestReport) {
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports123/allTests")
    // Include the results from the `test` task in all subprojects
    reportOn subprojects*.test
}
```

I have used testReport as per 
[Gradle docs Links](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/java_plugin.html#using_junit5)

When i run the Gradle task, It runs all the test case, generate XML reprts, but doesnot generate HTML report

In the build log, i see

> :testReport NO-SOURCE

any suggestion why it says NO-SOURCE ??

Thanks

Comment: Thank you. Yes, It looks duplicate as mine. Will mark this as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing one thing too many. You should either use 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin' or `test { useJUnitPlatform }` but not both.

The standard gradle (html) test reporting will only work with the latter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have removed org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin and i was able to generate html report without any extra config, but it doesnot consider dir src/main/java to scan test methods. It only scan src/test/java and execute all test case. is there any simple way where i can use sourceSet and use them in test task ?

Comment: I could find a way to consider src/main/java to scan test method. I have added below in gradle.build                                                           ...                                                                                                         
sourceSets {
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
        }
    }
}                                                                                                               Let me know if any better way